# Race conditions in HTTP Set-Cookie responses?

Tags: web, session, cookies, browser, frontend

Let's say you have an application that is going to set a cookie with a UUID. If there is already a cookie present with the same key then you will simply use the same value that already exists.

However, there would be a race condition if you made >=2 concurrent requests in the same browser and multiple values could be used for the same cookie and at least one would be overridden by another tab/window/etc.

Is this a realistic concern? If so can this be avoided without using a single key based on something in the client that would not change (not sure if anything like that exists) and then mapping it to something on the server?